# proc summary without first row (total summary)

Tags: sas

I am running the next code:

```
data test1;
input id m1 m2 m3 s1 s2 s3;
datalines;
1 1 2 3 500 1150 200
1 0 4 1 150 2000 430
2 0 0 4 396 396 789
2 10 4 8 150 170 430
3 5 8 9 100 150 240
3 6 0 1 140 270 698
;
run;

proc summary data=test1;
class id;
output out=test2 max(m1 m2 m3) = m11 m21 m31
                 sum(s1 s2 s3) = s11 s21 s31;
run;
```

The output:
[image]

I want the same output but without the first row which summarize the all rows.
Is there any option in proc summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `nway` to the `PROC SUMMARY` call:

```
proc summary data=test1 nway;
class id;
output out=test2 max(m1 m2 m3) = m11 m21 m31
                 sum(s1 s2 s3) = s11 s21 s31;
run;
```

Comment: Or  use `by` instead of `class` (your sample data is already sorted by ID, if your real data is not, then you would need to sort first).  Using `by` is technically a little faster, although probably not noticeable.